# C# read write lock on list

Tags: c#, timer

Desription:
   I am adding some data to list every second. After every 10 seconds, the data is saved to the database and then I clear the list. If I stop the timer, I am saving the data remaining in the list and then clearing the list and then stopping the timer.
In the above code, Let's say when I stop the timer after 11 seconds, The Class1s  list should have only 1 data, but I see  there are 11 datas. Can you guys tell what I am doing wrong here? Maybe my use of lock is incorrect or my code is totally incorrect

```
public class Class1Singleton
{
    private static Class1Singleton Class1Singleton;
    private static List<Class1> Class1s;
    private static Timer saveClass1Timer;
    private static readonly object lock1 = new object();
    private Class1Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Class1Singleton getInstance()
    {
        if (Class1Singleton == null) {
            try
            {
                Class1Singleton = new Class1Singleton();
            }
            catch (Exception e){}
        }
        return Class1Singleton;
    }

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        if (saveClass1Timer == null)
        {
            saveClass1Timer = new Timer(10000);
            //saveClass1Timer.Interval = 10000;
            saveClass1Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SaveClass1);
            saveClass1Timer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    public  void SaveClass1(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            lock (lock1)
            {
                new Class1Repository().InsertAllClass1(Class1s);
                ClearWorkoutList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}
    }

    public  void InsertClass1(List<Class1> Class1)
    {
        if (Class1s == null)
        {
            Class1s = new List<Class1>(Class1);
        }
        else
        {
            lock (lock1)
            {
                Class1s.AddRange(Class1);
            }
        }
    }

    public  void ClearWorkoutList()
    {
        if (Class1s != null)
        {
            Class1s.Clear();
        }
    }

    public  void StopTimer()
    {
        if (Class1s != null && Class1s.Count > 0)
        {
            lock (lock1)
            {
                new Class1Repository().InsertAllClass1(Class1s);
                ClearWorkoutList();
            }
        }
        if (saveClass1Timer != null && saveClass1Timer.Enabled == true)
        {
            saveClass1Timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of problems with your code:

1. Since the `InsertClass1` method of the `Class1Singleton` is called from the outside, you have no control over when such call can be made. 

2. You need to use lock over the list when you do `Clear` it.

3. When exactly do you check the number of 'datas' on the timer stop?

Comment: yes, InsertClass1 is called from outside and is called every second. I am never checking the no. of datas on timer stop. Since SaveClass1 is called every 10 second and this method also clears the list, so I'm assuming that the list inside stoptimer has always the correct data.

Comment: And lock is always there whenever ClearWorkoutList is called

Comment: I resolved the problem, but you said there's lot of problems with my code. Can You tell exaclty ?

Comment: You swallow the exceptions, it's a bad practice. You don't use locks properly in InsertClass1 when you create the list. ClearList is a public method but it doesn't have locks. Null checking has to be done before and after lock acquisition, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few changes to your code (see comments):

```
public class Class1Singleton
{
    // This is the way Jon Skeet recommends implementing a singleton in C#
    // See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx
    static readonly Class1Singleton instance = new Class1Singleton();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Class1Singleton() { }

    // There's only one instance of Class1Singleton so there's
    // no advantage in making the members static
    private List<Class1> Class1s;
    private Timer saveClass1Timer;
    private readonly object lock1 = new object();

    Class1Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Class1Singleton Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        // If you're using this class in a multi-thread environment,
        // all methods that access the list or timer should be locked
        lock (lock1)
        {
            if (saveClass1Timer == null)
            {
                saveClass1Timer = new Timer(10000);
                //saveClass1Timer.Interval = 10000;
                saveClass1Timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SaveClass1);
                saveClass1Timer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // SaveClass1 doesn't need to be public
    private void SaveClass1(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (lock1)
        {
            SaveWorkoutList();
            ClearWorkoutList();
        }            
    }

    private void SaveWorkoutList()
    {
        //new Class1Repository().InsertAllClass1(Class1s);
    }

    public void InsertClass1(List<Class1> Class1)
    {
        lock (lock1)
        {
            if (Class1s == null)
                Class1s = new List<Class1>(Class1);
            else
                Class1s.AddRange(Class1);
        }
    }

    private void ClearWorkoutList()
    {
        if (Class1s != null)
        {
            Class1s.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void StopTimer()
    {
        lock (lock1)
        {
            if (Class1s != null && Class1s.Count > 0)
            {
                SaveWorkoutList();
                ClearWorkoutList();
            }

            if (saveClass1Timer != null && saveClass1Timer.Enabled == true)
            {
                saveClass1Timer.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

}
```